# java.util.zip.zipexception : unknown compression method

Tags: java, zip

I am working with a third party API http://jortho.sourceforge.net/
While using the API, I always get an exception

```
java.util.zip.zipexception : unknown compression method
```

There are no zip files involved, I tried not using the .jar file of the API, instead using the class files directly, but it still gives me the same error.

What possibly could be the reason? How can I start off with my debugging?
There is a class WordIterator which uses `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` but I don't think the problem is with the API.

I am stuck! What can be the possible way out?

Comment: Please post complete stacktrace for your exception

Comment: There is no stacktrace! I get a JOPtionPane with the dialougue message! :|

Answer (score 2):

I sounds to me as if someone is trying to unzip a corrupted zip-file/stream, or something which isn't a zip-file or stream at all.

Since JOrtho is GPL, your best shot is to get the source code and debug the thing yourself. In Eclipse, you can set an exception breakpoint on `ZipException` and the debugger will stop immediately before the exception is thrown.