# JNPL with ULC 7.0 on Ubuntu throws ZipException

Tags: zip

Stacktrace follows below, but first my search results so far:

Somebody ran into a similar problem. Allegedly it was a problem with the ULCAppletPane in ULC 6.1. I am using ULC 7.0, so I guess I can safely forget those links.

Someone else had a similar ZipException with the very same readUTF() method of the InflaterInputStream. The proposed solution was to use readUTF() differently:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4529325

Is ULC using readUTF() wrong? In this similar InflaterInputStream.readUTF() issue on Stackoverflow, the proposed solution is to get the source code and debug the library with exception breakpoint.
[java.util.zip.zipexception : unknown compression method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274585/java-util-zip-zipexception-unknown-compression-method)
The search results on Stackoverflow (and also on Google) pretty much end there. The best idea I have now is to decompile the closed-source ULC library and debug it. Will I have to do that or can anybody help me with this issue?

[Client]
OS: Linux (3.0.0-32-generic, amd64)
Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. (1.6.0_26)
ULC: ULC Core (20206)

[Stacktrace]

```
com.ulcjava.base.client.ConnectorException: I/O exception has been thrown.
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ServletConnector.a(ServletConnector.java:81)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ServletConnector.b(ServletConnector.java:41)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ServletConnector.start(ServletConnector.java:88)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.UISession.startConnector(UISession.java:133)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.launcher.DefaultSessionStateListener.sessionStarted(DefaultSessionStateListener.java:13)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.UISession.a(UISession.java:114)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.UISession.access$16(UISession.java:92)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.UISession$0.run(UISession$0.java:6)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at com.ulcjava.base.client.FilteringEventQueue.dispatchEvent(FilteringEventQueue.java:55)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.IOConnectorCommandException: I/O exception has been thrown.
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ConnectorCommand.execute(ConnectorCommand.java:37)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ServletConnector.executeCommand(ServletConnector.java:22)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ServletConnector.a(ServletConnector.java:104)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: unknown compression method
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:248)
    at com.ulcjava.base.shared.internal.UlcDataInputStream.readByte(UlcDataInputStream.java:4)
    at com.ulcjava.base.shared.internal.UlcObjectInputStream.a(UlcObjectInputStream.java:67)
    at com.ulcjava.base.shared.internal.UlcObjectInputStream.readObject(UlcObjectInputStream.java:78)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.AbstractBasicAuthenticationCommand.handleResponse(AbstractBasicAuthenticationCommand.java:8)
    at com.ulcjava.container.servlet.client.ConnectorCommand.execute(ConnectorCommand.java:53)
    ... 24 more
```